# Binding with custom object for ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox

I am working on a WP8 project which needs to binding custom objects to a listbox item. Here is  how I am doing it:

XAML file:

```
<ListBox x:Name="mMenuList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tap="OnMenuListItemTapped" DataContext="{Binding Dest}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MenuTitle}" Visibility="Visible" FontSize="20" MaxWidth="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Image Source="/Assets/img/search_next_icon.png" Width="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Tap="OnGotoChildIconTapped"/>
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and a class for the data items:

```
public class PDFMenuItem
{
   private String _menuTitle;
   public String MenuTitle
   {
      get {  return _menuTitle; }
      set {  _menuTitle = value; }
   }

   private int _dest;
   public int Dest
   {
      get { return _dest;  }
      set { _dest = value; }
   }

   private Visibility _visibility;
   public Visibility Visibility
   {
     get { return _visibility; }
     set { _visibility = value; }
   }
}
```

Binding them together:

```
PDFMenuItem item = new PDFMenuItem();
item.MenuTitle = "Title";
item.Dest = "1";
item.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
mMenuList.Items.Add(item);
```

With the implementation, data for StackPanel and Image can be bind correctly, but nothing was bind to the TextBlock. How should I correct this? I also tried to add all items into a list and set it to mMenuList.ItemsSource. Nothing changed.

B.R./Alex

Comment: Why are you using DataContext for your StackPanel and binding to Dest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Once I've added a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20032671/2681948) which may help you - it is for LLS but works the same for ListBox.

ListBox which you are using usually works with Collections (for example List, ObservableCollection).
You have defined your item class, ok, then make a collection of your items:

```
ObservableCollection<PDFMenuItem> myCol = new ObservableCollection<PDFMenuItem>();
// add some items:
myCol.Add( new PDFMenuItem { MenuTitle = "Title", Dest = "1", Visibility = Visibility.Visible });
// then set it as ItemsSource to your ListBox
mMenuList.ItemsSource = myCol;
```

Your XAML also needs a little modification:

```
<ListBox x:Name="mMenuList">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tap="OnMenuListItemTapped">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MenuTitle}" Visibility="Visible" FontSize="20" MaxWidth="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Image Source="/Assets/img/search_next_icon.png" Width="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Tap="OnGotoChildIconTapped"/>
        </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I've thrown away `DataContext` as it will be set automatically when you set `ItemsSource`. Of course it can be also done different ways (especially if you use MVVM pattern), but in your simple example should work.

When you use `ObservableCollection` your `ListBox` will be automatically updated when you Add/Remove items, but it won't update if you change some properties in them - for this purpose you will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` - you will easily find many tutorials.

Comment: Hi Romasz. According to you reply, I find that the problem does not about the ObservableCollection, but about the DataContext in StackPanel. Once I remove the property, the problem solved. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AAAAlex Yes that was the main problem. IMO it is better to work with Collection of items rather than ListBox.Items itself.