# consume rest web service in TextBlocks

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to consume a rest web service that shows the name of each cuisine in stackPanels in my Grid like this:

[image]

but with my code,I get only the last element,How can I send each name of kitchen in a stackPanel ,this is my code:

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=nom}"        x:Name="nomCuisine"/> 
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

and this is my function:

```
 private async void GetListeCuisines()
        {
            UriString2 = "URL/cuisines.php";
            var http = new HttpClient();
            http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            var response = await http.GetStringAsync(UriString2);
            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Barberry.Models.RootObject>(response);
             for(int i=0; i < 2;i++)
            {
                nomCuisine.Text = rootObject.cuisines[i].nom;
            }
        }
```

this is my json data:

```
success: 1,
message: "cuisine found!",
cuisines: [
{
id: "1",
nom: "Cuisine 1"
},
{
id: "2",
nom: "Cuisine 2"
}
]
```

thanks for help

Update:

I set my code to this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBlock Text="" x:Name="nomCuisine"/> 
                    </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

and this is the function:

```
private async void GetListeCuisines()
        {
            UriString2 = "myURL/cuisines.php";
            var http = new HttpClient();
            http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            var response = await http.GetStringAsync(UriString2);
            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Barberry.Models.RootObject>(response);
             for(int i=0; i < 2;i++)
            {
                string items= rootObject.cuisines[i].nom;
            }}
```

this time I get nothing as a result :(

Comment: Sure, you get last element, as in your loop every item overwrites the previous one. I think instead of using one textblock inside stackpanel, maybe think of using listview with itemtemplate set as textblock and then just set *ItemsSource* as your collection.

Comment: thanks Sir,then how can I bound to that collection?

Comment: For the very simple case (binding just strings), just declare ItemTemplate as datatemplate with `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>`. Then set `yourListView.ItemsSource = yourStringArray/stringCollection;`. There are plenty of blogs/articles and so on how to handle listview. You may also take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20032671/2681948) - it's for long list selector, but basic sample for listview will look the same.

Comment: thanks Romasz,it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
<ListView x:Name="cuisineListview">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding nom}" x:Name="nomCuisine"/> 
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And:

```
private async void GetListeCuisines()
{
    UriString2 = "myURL/cuisines.php";
    var http = new HttpClient();
    http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
    var response = await http.GetStringAsync(UriString2);
    cuisineListview.ItemsSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Barberry.Models.RootObject>(response).cuisines;
}
```

But I suggest you to learn how to use MVVM so you can have cleaner code.