# Async method binds data not on firstload but on second load in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, async-await, uwp

I have an async method. I am trying to bind listview from a json file on web.
I am developing an Universal Windows Platform App. The list view is being loaded when I open the page on second time. But off course I want list view loaded on first load. What can cause the problem for it? Thanks.
This is the codebehind of my XAML.

```
 public MyPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Namedays =  new List<NamedayModel>();
        LoadData();
        listview1.ItemsSource = Namedays;
    }

    public async void LoadData()
    {
        Namedays = await GetAllNamedaysAsync();
    }

    private static List<NamedayModel> allNamedaysCache;

    public static async Task<List<NamedayModel>> GetAllNamedaysAsync()
    {
        if (allNamedaysCache != null)
            return allNamedaysCache;

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.example.com/myfile.json");

        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<NamedayModel>));
        allNamedaysCache = (List<NamedayModel>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

        return allNamedaysCache;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The are couple of things you make wrong:

- **don't** make *async void* if not really needed (for example events),
- your are running your `LoadData()` in constructor as *fire-forget*, it doesn't await (it's also impossible in constructor), the code goes further and you set listview's itemssource to *Namedays*. You are not using binding for *ItemsSource*, thus when you change *Namedays* in loaded method, it's not reflected by listview.
- apart from that, also by asigning new value to *Namedays* in `LoadData()`, you don't change the value of listview's itemssource - it's still pointing to old collection.

Much better in this case would be if you had used binding for *ItemsSource*, define property and load data asynchronously in for example *Loaded* event. Sample code, XAML:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Namedays}"/>
```

And the code behind:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaiseProperty(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    private List<NamedayModel> namedays = new List<NamedayModel>();
    public List<NamedayModel> Namedays { get { return namedays; } set { namedays = value; RaiseProperty(nameof(Namedays)); } }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Namedays = await GetAllNamedaysAsync();
    }

    public static async Task<List<NamedayModel>> GetAllNamedaysAsync()
    {
        if (allNamedaysCache != null)
            return allNamedaysCache;

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.tyosoft.com/namedays_hu.json");

        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<NamedayModel>));
        allNamedaysCache = (List<NamedayModel>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

        return allNamedaysCache;
    }
}
```

As a side note - you may also think of using *ObservableCollection* instead of *List* if you want to modify it without reassigning.

Comment: Thank you Romasz. But VS give me "object reference required" error here in this code block in RaiseProperty    ||                                                                                public static List<NamedayModel> Namedays
        {
            get { return namedays; }
            set { namedays = value; RaiseProperty(nameof(Namedays)); }
        }  ||

Comment: @oneNiceFriend Yeah, I have put code from the top of my head. Your lists cannot be static - *PropertyChanged event* is connected with class instance and thus it cannot be static.

Comment: that solved my problem. @Romasz Thank you. Do I load the json just once during the session? right? And there is one other thing. This is the xaml part of listview. <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Namedays}"/>  How can I bind certain column to list view? for example name, surname etc. Because now it just shows ProjectName.NameDayModel in listview.

Comment: @oneNiceFriend You will need to provide *ItemTemplate* for your *ListView* and in defined *DataTemplate*, bind to suitable properties of your *NameDayModel*. [This answer may help little](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20032671/2681948).

Comment: Allright. I managed it. BUt what about my other concern?  Do I load the json just once during the session? or Do I load the data everytime user loads the page?

Comment: @oneNiceFriend Everything depends on your needs - you can do it once, or every time user loads page, but if the data hasn't changed then I see no purpose in loading it once again.

Comment: Yes I think so, there is  no purpose in loading it once again. I am asking about the code you provided.  In your code, Am I loading the data once during the session? or Am I loading it everytime user click? this is my last question:)

Comment: @oneNiceFriend Just debug it. *Loaded* event can be fired multiple times, but as I think you already has handled this issue by `if (allNamedaysCache != null) return allNamedaysCache;`. For such questions always debug your program - you will find the answer faster than writing a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your `listview1` does not know about the data so it does not load them. When you open the page for second time, data is already loaded and `listview1` can display them.

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface like so:

```
 protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

and then call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Namedays))` after you load your data