# Updating a countdown inside a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, win-universal-app

I want to make a countdown on each item in a `ListView`, but it won't update. I try to call the property in the tick event raised by the dispatcher timer, but that won't work to. Any advise on how I can achieve this?

```cs
public ObservableCollection<TimeAndName> items { get; set; }
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(); 
    public MyViewModel()
    {        
                LoadItems();
                TimeMethod();                   
    }
    public void TimeMethod()
    {
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        timer.Tick += myTimer_tick;        
        timer.Start();
    }
    public void LoadItems()
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<TimeAndName>();
        items.Add(new TimeAndName("first item", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 0), ""));            
    }
    private void myTimer_tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        foreach (var timeAndName in items)
        {
            var now = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("T"));
            var deadline = DateTime.Parse(timeAndName.Deadline.ToString());
            TimeSpan dif = now - deadline;
            timeAndName.TimeString = dif.ToString();
        }             
    }
    #region NotifyRegion
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    } 
    #endregion
```

XAML:

```xml
<Grid Background="#FF22313F">
  <Grid.DataContext>
     <local:MyViewModel/>
  </Grid.DataContext>
  <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding items, Mode=TwoWay,         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="360" Margin="1047,196,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="467" Background="#FF574C89"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Does your *timeAndName* items implement *INotifyPropertyChanged*?

Comment: yes, and all the properties contains OnPropertyChanged method.

Comment: How have you defined binding in your item template?

Comment: itemsource= items
mode = twoway
updatesourcetrigger = propertychanged

Comment: Can you put your itemtemplate xaml part in your question?

Comment: xaml code is added now :)

Comment: Seems like you have bound only collection of items, without defining *ItemTemplate*. [Here you have sample](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20032671/2681948), though this one doesn't have *INotifyPropertyChanged* implemented.

Comment: i didn't think that would make a difference, but i will try it out.

Comment: It definitely makes a difference - as for now you have bound to ObservableCollection and it **only** updates listview if items are added/removed - **not** modified - if you declare itemtemplate with binding and *INotifyPropertyChanged*, it will work.

Comment: it works! thank you very much :) i didn't know that declaring the itemtemplate will allow you to modify the items, thank you for sharing the knowledge ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have bound only collection of items, without defining suitable *ItemTemplate*. A sample can look like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding items, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="360" Margin="1047,196,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="467" Background="#FF574C89">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeString}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

As for now, you have bound to ObservableCollection and it only updates *ListView* if items are added/removed - **not modified** - if you declare *ItemTemplate* with binding and *INotifyPropertyChanged*, it will work.